# Data visibility between linked server

Tags: sql-server

Please consider the following situation 
I have Prod instance of SQL server 2012
Also Archive instance of SQL server express 2012

Prod sees Archive as linked server and is able to write data with similar query from some .net code that creates a transaction and the transaction is committed at the end.

```
insert into <ArchiveServer>.<database>.<schema>.<table> 
Select * from <ProductionServer>.<database>.<schema>.<table> Where <some conditions>
```

Now after the transaction finishes I am able to execute the following query

```
select count(1) from <ArchiveServer>.<database>.<schema>.<table>
```

and it returns correct number of records in the context of production server.

Same query

```
select count(1) from <database>.<schema>.<table>
```

in the context of Archive server returned 0 records.

What might be the problem? I am out of clues.

Thanks

Comment: Are these statements in a BEGIN / COMMIT TRANSACTION?

Comment: @kevchadders the transaction is handled by .net code ... basically yes as answer to your comment.

Comment: Are you defining isolation level related to row versioning and not commiting the transaction..??

Comment: @RajeshRanjan nothing like this. Perhaps the corpse is hidden in proper linking of the servers.. i am investigating.

Comment: The problem was in how the linked server was defined. Probably i missed something. Did it through the UI interface and it worked like a charm.